useState isn't reflecting a change in an onClick callback function
I am new to React, and I am having the following issue:
When I get a value from redux, I am creating a clone of it and saving it to useState so I can modify it without affecting the original value until I press save, which then sends the value to redux to be updated in my store. The problem I am having, is in the function saveProject the value doesn't change name within the object, as it is still the original value. However, in the effect, the correct value is displayed. I am not sure why, what would be causing this?
Here is an example (Open the console to see output).
Note: I have tried changing defaultValue to value, but then I cannot type into the input box which leads me to believe maybe there is something else going on?
const [isEditDialogOpen, setIsEditDialogOpen] = useState(true);

return (
  {isEditDialogOpen && <EditProjectDialog onClose={() => setIsEditDialogOpen(false)} />}
)

// Simplified: <Dialog />
export default ({ children }) => {
  const DialogOutput = <div>{children}</div>

  return <>{createPortal(DialogOutput,document.body)}</>
}

// Edit dialog: <EditProjectDialog />
export default () => {
  // Original value from redux
  const active = useSelector(selectActiveProject);
  // The value I want to track
  const [project, setProject] = useState<Project>(Object.assign({}, active));
  // The value should be the updated value here (but shows the original)
  const saveProject = () => console.log(project);
  // Sets the value when the input is typed into
  const nameChange = (e: BaseSyntheticEvent) => setProject({ ...project, name: e.target.value });

  // Prints the correct value from the input
  useEffect(() => console.log('useEffect', project), [project]);

  return (
    <Dialog>
      <input defaultValue={project.name} onChange={nameChange} />
      <button onClick={saveProject}>Save</button>
    </Dialog>
  );
}



The problem exists with the way the dialog is setup not the input being value instead of defaultValue. Still trying to narrow down what is specifically causing it

I am not so sure that this isn't working as much as that the saveProject function has the initial version of project. To check if this is the problem I would make a useCallback function:
useCallback(() => console.log(project), [project])

Other than that typically you want to use the value field instead of the defaultValue because the defaultValue field makes this an uncontrolled component and it doesn't seem like that's what you want in this case :)
Edit: An implementation of value instead of defaultValue
export default () => {
 const active = useSelector(selectActiveProject);
 const [project, setProject] = useState<Project>(Object.assign({}, active));
 const saveProject = () => console.log(project);

 const nameChange = (e: BaseSyntheticEvent) => 
  setProject((prevProject) => ({
   ...prevProject,
   name: e.target.value,
  }));;

  useEffect(() => console.log('useEffect', project), [project]);

  return (
    <Dialog>
      <input value={project.name} onChange={nameChange} />
      <button onClick={saveProject}>Save</button>
    </Dialog>
  );
}

This should properly update the name value of project and allow you to edit the input, if it does not show me the variation of code that is failing for you and I will try my best to debug it :)
Edit: Dialog Problems addressed :)
So the useEffect you have within the Dialog is missing a dependency and is only rendering when you initially render the page.
useEffect(() => {
if (typeof closeOnBackdrop !== 'undefined')
  setBackDropClick(closeOnBackdrop);
if (!(children instanceof Array)) {
  setContentElement(children);
  return;
}
setTitleElement(children.find((child) => child?.type === DialogTitle));
setContentElement(children.find((child) => child?.type === DialogContent));
setActionsElement(children.find((child) => child?.type === DialogActions));
console.log('CONTENT ELEMENT', contentElement);
}, []);

Because of this when we changed to the input value, which is react controlled, the value was constantly being reset to Example because the Dialog never updated when its children changed(like the text being updated).
You can remedy this by simply adding children to the dependency array:
useEffect(..., [children]);

The reason this was working with defaultValue is because this is controlled by just the DOM and ignores what React wants to do with it.

If I use value, then I can't type into the input field, so what i read was to use defaultValue.

That is only if you are not managing the state of that value properly, the following little example I created shows when managed properly value does work

I have tried to mimic your example, but I still cannot type into the input box.

useEffect(..., [children]); indeed fixes my issue thanks!

The problem is with the defaultValue props.
defaultValue vs value:

defaultValue: Sets the initial value of an uncontrolled component. It does not update after the initial render, so subsequent changes to the state won’t affect the input value.
value: Controls the input field directly. The input will re-render and reflect any changes in the state immediately.

I believe that it will work if you change to
<input value={project.name} onChange={nameChange} />


I have tried that, but then I cannot type into the input box.
